# How to generate number between 1-99 from existing mysql table column?

Tags: php, mysql, numbers

i have such mysql db table:

```
id name    surname number
1  emil    asadi   26
2  anybody anybody 27
```

I want to check **number** column-> that is if number not exists between 1-99 then generate new number from beginning of 1.New number also should be between 1-99.

How can can i do that with ***for*** function and mysql query? Or do you know any other way? Thank you in adnavce

Comment: but this has to be done at insert time? i mean: when you add a row you want to set a number [1-99] to column number that does not exists already? what if all 1-99 numbers exists?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can generate random number using single query not starting from 1 using below query. And i don't think it will matter:

```
 SELECT id, name, surname,
 if(number between 1 and 99 ,number,floor(1 + rand() * 99)) as number
 FROM table
```

Let me know if this is same you want.

Comment: Did you mean `FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 99))`? `round(1 + rand() * 100)` produces numbers in the range 1 - 101.

Comment: Yes.. both will give same result

Comment: No. `FLOOR(1 + (RAND() * 99))` gives numbers in the range 1 - 99 whereas `round(1 + rand() * 100)` gives numbers in the range 1 - 101.

Comment: No. As round will round up resulting in a value of 100. rand() * 99 could equal 98.99. Add 1 = 99.99. Rounding then gives 100.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this SQL-Statement to get your gaps between your numbers.
If you have your gaps, you can use the result in a function which fires a UPDATE-Statement.

```
SELECT a.number+1 AS start, MIN(b.number) - 1 AS end
FROM database AS a, database AS b
WHERE a.number < b.number
GROUP BY a.number
HAVING start < MIN(b.number)
```